# How do I remove the layer of control box of the second(child) form within the MDI form as parent form in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, desktop-application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace SchoolDemo
{
    public partial class MDI : Form
    {
        public MDI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MDI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Demo naya = new Demo();
            {
                naya.MdiParent = this;
                naya.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            };
            naya.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

[^This is the code of my MDI form]

[In the right hand corner you can see there is a extra layer of max, min and close options.
I have already disabled control box in child form but I am still getting this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bF7s.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to remove the layer of control box of the child

form.

You can try the following code to solve this problem.

Child form code:

```
  private void Demo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ControlBox = false;
        }
```